# Instagram like Social networking using mongodb and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, social-networking, graph-databases

I am using mongodb with node js in my application. We have users collection and events collection.

```
Users :-  "user":{
"name":[name],
"email":[email]

}

Events :-  "event":{
"title":[title],
"venue":[venue]

}
```

Previously users can only follow events but cannot follow each other now i am also making social networking around users also, so users can follow each other and their feed will get changed accordingly exactly like Instagram.

so my question is as my main database is Mongodb, so should i make this social networking using Mongodb only or should i use some Graph db and put all my user data from Mongo db to Graph db and maintain both the databases simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to put an express server running [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) in front of Mongo using [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql). If you define a user type and an event type you could write a graphql query something like:

```
query {
   user(name: "Sally") {
     followed_users {
       name
     }
     followed_events {
       title
     }
   }
}
```

This essentially presents your data as a graph, but graphql would be triggering a flurry of mongodb queries (look at the resolve function [here](http://graphql.org/docs/getting-started/) and imagine a Mongo query instead of data[args.id]) behind the scenes to get all that info and then combining it into a single JSON response.

A more invasive option would be to switch from MongoDB to [ArangoDB](http://www.arangodb.com/).
It is a document store like MongoDB, so it should feel pretty familiar, but if you add an extra collection of edges (another document with _to: and _from: attributes) then you have an actual graph and can do actual joins, traversals and transactions in the DB.

While GraphQL just presents your data as a graph, ArangoDB is actually a [full-on graph database](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html). Either way you can addresses your problem without forcing yourself to deal with the complexity and cost of multiple data stores.